# Flex container: only show 4 or 2 per row depending on screen size

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My goal is to have eight 200px-by-200px squares appear on a row, centered, with some text in the middle.

I want to set it so that these 8 squares show side-by-side, 4 on top then 4 on the bottom. Then, when the screen shrinks, they show 2 in a row in 4 rows. I don't want there to ever be 3 or 1 squares in a row. I got something working but it shows 1 when the browsing on a small screen like a phone.

Any ideas?

```
.reccontainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 1em;
    padding: 40px calc((100% - (240px * 4)) / 2);
}

.recsquare {
    flex: 0 0 200px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .reccontainer {
        padding: 40px calc((100% - (240px * 2)) / 2);
    }
}
```

```
<div class="reccontainer">
            <div class="recsquare">
                <p>Test.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="recsquare">
                <p>Test.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="recsquare">
                <p>Test.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="recsquare">
                <p>Test.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="recsquare">
                <p>Test.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="recsquare">
                <p>Test.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="recsquare">
                <p>Test.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="recsquare">
                <p>Test.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use width on your container and center the container.

Adjust the width for any gap and apply a suitable media query to change the width.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  outline: 1px solid grey;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: calc(800px + 3em);
  gap: 1em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: calc(800px + 3em)) {
  .wrap {
    width: calc(400px + 3em);

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/jOJdxGr?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by using a grid instead of flex-wrap.

You can specify how many columns each row should have, along with their sizes using the `grid-template-columns` property.

Just adjust the template for your desired screen widths using a media query.

[Here is some useful documentation on it](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/g/grid-template-columns/).

```css
/* container used to center the reccontainer on the page */
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.reccontainer {
  display: grid;
  width: fit-content;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px 200px; /* 4 x 200px columns */
  gap: 1em;
}

.recsquare {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  
  /* center text horizontally and vertically */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* switch to 2 x 200px columns at 850px */
@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {
  .reccontainer {
    grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="reccontainer">
    <div class="recsquare">
      <p>Test.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="recsquare">
      <p>Test.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="recsquare">
      <p>Test.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="recsquare">
      <p>Test.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="recsquare">
      <p>Test.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="recsquare">
      <p>Test.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="recsquare">
      <p>Test.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="recsquare">
      <p>Test.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```